# Check if field of one array of objects is missing from another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Say we have an array of objects like this:

```
var array1 = 
[
 {first_name: 'Bob', last_name: 'Jones', email: 'bobjones@gmail.com'},
 {first_name: 'Susan', last_name: 'Anderson', email: 'susananderson@gmail.com'}
]

var array2 =
[
 {first_name: 'Bob', last_name: 'Jones', email: 'bobjones@gmail.com'},
 {first_name: 'Susan', last_name: 'Anderson', email: 'susananderson@gmail.com'},
 {first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith', email: 'johnsmith@gmail.com'}
]
```

I want to detect if any row in array2 is missing based on email address, and if it's missing set a new status `active` to false so that the final array will come out to this:

```
var array3 = [
 {first_name: 'Bob', last_name: 'Jones', email: 'bobjones@gmail.com'},
 {first_name: 'Susan', last_name: 'Anderson', email: 'susananderson@gmail.com'},
 {first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith', email: 'johnsmith@gmail.com', active: false}
]
```

I tried looping through each element in both, but it proved to be slow for when I had lot's of elements in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `forEach` loop and a `filter`

```js
var array1 = 
[
 {first_name: 'Bob', last_name: 'Jones', email: 'bobjones@gmail.com'},
 {first_name: 'Susan', last_name: 'Anderson', email: 'susananderson@gmail.com'}
]

var array2 =
[
 {first_name: 'Bob', last_name: 'Jones', email: 'bobjones@gmail.com'},
 {first_name: 'Susan', last_name: 'Anderson', email: 'susananderson@gmail.com'},
 {first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith', email: 'johnsmith@gmail.com'}
]
array2.forEach((e)=>{
array1.filter(k=>e.email==k.email).length==0?e.active="false":false;
})
console.log(array2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

- change array1 to `Map`, so the accessing email from array1 can be done in O(1)
- Loop over array2, add `active` key conditionally based on the presence of email in `newMap`

```js
let array1 = [{first_name: 'Bob', last_name: 'Jones', email: 'bobjones@gmail.com'},{first_name: 'Susan', last_name: 'Anderson', email: 'susananderson@gmail.com'}]
let array2 =[{first_name: 'Bob', last_name: 'Jones', email: 'bobjones@gmail.com'}, {first_name: 'Susan', last_name: 'Anderson', email: 'susananderson@gmail.com'}, {first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith', email: 'johnsmith@gmail.com'}]
let newMap = new Map(array1.map(({email})=>[email,true]))

let final = array2.map(obj=>({
    ...obj,
    ...(!newMap.has(obj.email) && {active: false})
  })
)

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can maintain a set of all the emails from the array1 and than use `Array.map()` on array2 to get the desired result:

```js
let array1 = [ {first_name: 'Bob', last_name: 'Jones', email: 'bobjones@gmail.com'}, {first_name: 'Susan', last_name: 'Anderson', email: 'susananderson@gmail.com'} ]
let array2 =[ {first_name: 'Bob', last_name: 'Jones', email: 'bobjones@gmail.com'}, {first_name: 'Susan', last_name: 'Anderson', email: 'susananderson@gmail.com'}, {first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Smith', email: 'johnsmith@gmail.com'} ];

let set = new Set(array1.map(({email})=> email));

let array3 = array2.map(o =>{
  if(!set.has(o.email))
    o.active = false;
   return o;
});
console.log(array3);
```